# How to remove specific nested object from array of arrays

Tags: arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

How to remove an item from an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "category": "CC",
    "paymentOptions": [
      {
        "payCode": "v",
        "description": "Visa"
      },
      {
        "payCode": "m",
        "description": "Master"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "PayPal",
    "paymentOptions": [
      {
        "payCode": "PY",
        "description": "Paypal"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to remove this section from the above array of objects:

```
{
  "payCode": "m",
  "description": "Master"
}
```

After removing the above section my array should be like:

```
[
  {
    "category": "CC",
    "paymentOptions": [
      {
        "payCode": "v",
        "description": "Visa"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "PayPal",
    "paymentOptions": [
      {
        "payCode": "PY",
        "description": "Paypal"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried the below code but does not return the desired result:

```
this.payments.filter(x => x.paymentOptions.filter(x => x.description.toLowerCase() !="Master"))
```

How to do that? I need the output as above after removing the specific object.

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried.

Comment: I have tried to filter as  below but not getting the desiered result
var test =this.payments.filter(x => x.paymentOptions.filter(x => x.description.toLowerCase() !="Master"))
@HassanImam

Comment: @Nishanth please include the code in the question itself (with the "Edit" link under it), comments are not made to last and can be removed/converted to chat discussions. For your code there is an obvious issue: you use `toLowerCase` and compare to `"Master"` which is capitalized, so every element will pass this test. To add to that, using a filter call as test for the first filter call will probably not work, a condition is expected here, and filter returns an array which is always truthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to remove the item with `description`: "master" in `paymentOptions` array for each element in the `payments` array.

1. With `x.description.toLowerCase() !="Master"`, this will be never be `true`.
2. Use the `Array.map()` to iterate and update the `paymentOptions` array for each element.

```
let result = this.payments.map(x => ({
  ...x,
  paymentOptions: x.paymentOptions.filter(y => y.description.toLowerCase() != "master")
}));
```

[Demo @ TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBADghgngWxAOzAZwFwRsuBtAXQgF4I8AoCCAb0qogCIBjGMEAcwHsAnOBrBgGFBDADR0qDWIhRgA8lDABLTsjT8yE+rXq7G0wZwAmIDQwBuYrboYm0TbksUrkZgGpK0MBtYgBfcT0aX0kDY1MBBCsgyTsHJ2VVMwBZGDQ2bh8gvy0COgC6HXpmVg4ePgEABXhq4Gji6SRUBUS1DQogoqCpeEMTM0qATXruuMdnJKr4WDrfHN08qj8CAG5ycnMYbgg2dJJoeCb0ADoEGCgACgAPEgA+CAui4+erwIOZZom1LCvjxtkWi40McAGZKYAZC5wO4QODHMYJFzHMCcAAynAA7iBuII0iALgBKCAAQlIDDO6WxDAJ5D8BIJayYqjQnFAx2AnHYF12YAZQA)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple mistakes in your code:

- Your first call to filter's result is not retreived: `filter` returns an array and doesn't modify the original array. You must get the result, for example `this.payments = this.payments.filter(...);`
- using a filter call as test for another filter call will probably not work, a condition is expected here, and filter returns an array which is always truthy. The result of the inner filter call will also not be stored
- you use toLowerCase and compare to "Master" which is capitalized, so every element will pass this test

You can try a combination of `map` and `filter` like this

```js
this.payments = [
  {
    "category": "CC",
    "paymentOptions": [
        {
            "payCode": "v",
            "description": "Visa"
        },
        {
            "payCode": "m",
            "description": "Master"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "PayPal",
    "paymentOptions": [
        {
            "payCode": "PY",
            "description": "Paypal"
        }
    ]
  }
];

var result = this.payments.map(a => {
  a.paymentOptions = a.paymentOptions.filter( x => x.description.toLowerCase() != 'master' );
  return a;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any more the "original" array, you can simple use forEach

```
this.payments.forEach(x => {
  paymentOptions: x.paymentOptions
           .filter(y => y.description.toLowerCase() != "master")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, all other answers suggest `array = array.filter(…)` approach.

There are many other approaches though, and one of them would be to actually *find* and actually *remove* the undesired items (rather than substitute the original array with a new one that doesn't have the undesired items). So, importantly, this approach changes the original value.

```
interface Item {
  category: string
  paymentOptions: Array<{
    payCode: string
    description: string
  }>
}

function removePaymentOptions(category: string, payCode: string, items: Item[]): void {
  // find the to-be-updated items
  const itemsToUpdate = items.filter((item) => item.category === category)

  // find the undesired payment options in each of the item
  for (const item of itemsToUpdate) {
    const optionIndex = item.paymentOptions.findIndex((option) => option.payCode === payCode)

    // if the payment option exists, remove it from the item
    if (optionIndex !== -1) {
      item.paymentOptions.splice(optionIndex, 1)
    }
  }
}

const items = /* your array */

removePaymentOptions('CC', 'm', items)

// `items` is now updated to _not_ have the undesired payment options
```